# Generic HTML5 support for IE8

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have developed a simple asp.net site for data tracking. I almost have to project to completion but am stuck with the usual IE compatibility issues. So far under the head of my layout view I have the following

```
<![if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="../../Content/js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]
```

What i am wondering is -
1) Is there any generic files [.js/.css] that adapt for IE
2) Are there any programs available that can scan my site and throw back the issues on why IE is having problems reading the site.

Comment: What compatibility issues exactly? The 2 libraries above simply add missing HTML5 functionality (new elements + mediaqueries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[modernizr](http://modernizr.com) is a feature detection library for HTML5/CSS3 that can help to identify elements that are causing compatibility issues.